# Expected Shipping Date - Is it possible to get from magento 2 ? If yes then which table?

Tags: php, checkout, orders, shipping, order-history

Is it possible to get the expected shipping date to get it from some magento table.
I need to show this information in my invoice. Which table shows this information.

Shipped by: FedEx

`Expected by: 2-Jan-2021`

Please let me know any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe it will come from `sales_shipping_aggregated_order` So you can check its field `period`.

Comment: @viru - I checked the table sales_shipping_aggregated_order and now i am sure its not comming from there, also i checked 15 more table having keyword 'ship' but i have not found it anywhere. I doubt if magento is having this feature...